# Is it bad to use srand or loops in a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, neural-network

Sorry, could somebody explain is it a bad practice to create a loop in constructors and, for example, use a function srand () in a constructor? ( I am new in a C++, try to create neural network from scratch in a c++ using class) Thank you !

```cpp
class Neuro {    // class with random inputs and weight 
 

    public:

    std::vector <double> Inputs;
    std::vector <double> Weigh;
    std::vector <double> Neuron;
    //double activefunc (double);



    Neuro() { // generic random inputs and weights

        for (int i=0;i<3;i++){

        srand( (unsigned) time (NULL)); 
        Inputs.push_back((float)rand() / RAND_MAX);
        Weigh.push_back((float)rand() / RAND_MAX);
        Neuron.push_back(Inputs[i] * Weigh[i]); }   };
    
        double activefunc(double n){ ;
        return (((exp(n) - exp(-n)) / (exp(-n) + exp(n)))); } 
 
 };
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand - "Seeds the pseudo-random number generator ... Generally speaking, the pseudo-random number generator should only be seeded once" Calling `srand` multiple times would being reinitializing the random number generator repeatedly. Not a good thing for getting random results from it.

Comment: You probably better have parameters for these vectors, and fill them outside. This will make testing easier.

Comment: A loop in a constructor is fine unless the loop itself is a problem.

Comment: @user4581301: that would mean any library using random numbers must not call srand() because it can't know whether I called srand before. *That*'s weird to me.

Comment: Side note: [Rand Considered Harmful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/goingnative-2013/rand-considered-harmful)

Comment: If you want to properly deal with the possibility of exceptions in a constructor, loops can make the logic more complex, since you cannot rely on the destructor for cleanup. Since there are no resources without ownership in your constructor there are no such issues in your constructor implementation. There are techniques that allow you to keep the code simple regardless, but in some scenarios it can make a difference in the complexity of the constructor logic.

Comment: @ThomasWeller That sounds rather reasonable to me. Library code should not call `srand` under any circumstances. It should be explicitly user's choice to call it or not. I can for example call `srand` with constant value to test the code, or choose a random seed initializer. If library code would call `srand` internally, I couldn't have that choice.

Answer (score 0):

What is bad is unexpected behavior, such as "hidden" random seed modification or time-consuming loops. These usually don't happen in a constructor, so can puzzle the users.

Anyway, if such behaviors are obvious from context (i.e. a programmer would spontaneously be tempted to implement the class this way) or if they are clearly documented (in such a way that the user does not miss that information), then you are free.